# How to add native ad to firebase listview ui android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, admob, firebaseui

Is there a way to add native ad to firebase listview ui where after every 6th item an ad is viewed. My example code is ad below

```
listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Getters>(
        this,
        Getters.class,
        R.layout.search_layout,
        retrieveFollowers
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, final Getters model, int position) {

        TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
        username.setText(model.getUsername());
        TextView names = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        names.setText(model.getName());
        ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile);
        Picasso.with(Followers.this).load(model.getProfileImage()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4)).centerCrop().fit().into(profileImage);

    }
};
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Can someone please help me here

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest way which i used was to use [admobadapter](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter) you can customise this adapter as per your need like this :

```
    adapterWrapper.setLimitOfAds(3);      
    adapterWrapper.setNoOfDataBetweenAds(10);
    adapterWrapper.setFirstAdIndex(2);
```

to get an idea of how to use this library, check the [sample app's code](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/blob/master/sampleapp/src/main/java/com/clockbyte/admobadapter/sampleapp/MainActivity_ListView.java)

Comment: its really hard to understand can you use it using my example code above please

Comment: Sorry, Nobody here is gonna write code for you, we can just help you by giving you an idea of how to do it but not to do all the work.